# "Congratulations! Thanks to your efforts you have earned" box appears on top of the hat picker

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, winter-bash-2015

Normally the hat picker is on top of the "Badges" box in your activity tab, but when there's a "Congratulations" there, the hat picker appears behind it:

[image]

Also, as @MikeMiller mentions, the hat disappears after you click "let us pick".

Comment: You there in the blue woolly hat, I can see you hiding back there!

Comment: In fact, once you click "Let us pick", the blue hat goes away altogether!

Comment: @Mike I've included it in the question.

Comment: This message in my achievements inbox just confused me pretty bad. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5I8V.png I thought I had earned some very strang tag badge...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fixed, thanks.

Now stop earning badges and start earning hats!

Comment: [cough cough](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271607/double-hats-on-profile-page).

Comment: @ShadowWizard , I am afraid that user took balpha's advice too seriously.

Comment: @PythonMaster how so? Only 22 hats. :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard , don't you mean 34: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/62429/quill-hat-maniac?tab=topactivity  ? :)

Comment: @PythonMaster but that's not the OP here. Anyway... let's stop pinging poor balpha with notifications before he gets mad and take away all our hats... :-D