# Hat on profile disappears after acknowledging an earned badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page, winter-bash-2015

On the *Activity* section of the profile page, there's a little blue hat in the top-right corner of the badge section. When I receive a badge, it gets partially covered by a congratulatory message. When I press "Let us pick" to dismiss the message, or dismiss it by any other means, **the blue hat in the corner disappears entirely.**

The fact that the message partially covers the hat seems like it is probably an intentional feature, [and is addressed elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271286/congratulations-thanks-to-your-efforts-you-have-earned-box-appears-on-top-of?rq=1).

The fact that the hat disappears after dismissing the message seems like it is a separate issue, and probably unintentional/undesired.

> [image]

Comment: @nicael It is a separate issue, and IMHO should be a separate question. I find it entirely plausible that the one issue was intentional and the other unintentional.

Comment: You may want to specify that the bug is triggered not only by the "let us decide" button, but also by manually choosing the next badge to track.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Thanks for the heads up. Question edited.

Comment: Don't worry, my pleasure. Anyway, to be more precise, I wasn't just referring to the "Track the next one" link. I meant that even if you come days after and use the little gear next to the tracked badge to select a new badge to track, as soon as the chose popup closes, the hat button disappear too.

Comment: For me, it seems that the icon comes back after the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right, they were two different issues. They're both fixed now.