# Clicking "Let us pick" button removes the hat from the top right corner

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

Feels like a regression of an old bug we had in 2015:

- [Hat on profile disappears after acknowledging an earned badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271426/hat-on-profile-disappears-after-acknowledging-an-earned-badge)
- ["Congratulations! Thanks to your efforts you have earned" box appears on top of the hat picker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271286/congratulations-thanks-to-your-efforts-you-have-earned-box-appears-on-top-of)

Steps to reproduce:

- get the next badge you've been "tracking"
- navigate to the "Activity" page, see:
  [image]
- click "Let us pick", see *the hat image link from the top right disappeared*:
  [image]

Have not yet checked if clicking "Track the next one" would have the same effect.

Comment: 29 hat's . Impressive :)