# Double hats on profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, winter-bash-2015

I just earned a tag badge, and the "Congratulations!" box had another copy of my hat-tally added to it:

[image]

Whaddup-wid-hat?

Comment: Looks like a side effect of fixing [this other bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271286/congratulations-thanks-to-your-efforts-you-have-earned-box-appears-on-top-of). :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard by "side effect" you mean that it puts a second icon *on the side* of the first, right?

Comment: Not sure about the specific details @SPA, maybe the fix was changing the way the hat is attached to the box, and he forgot there are two boxes with same class