# Duplicate Winterbash hats in profile when earning a tag badge

Tags: bug, profile-page, winter-bash-2016

When you've earned a tag badge, the "Congratulation!" box also carries a Winterbash [toque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toque).

[image]

It's a small glitch, but one none the less.

Comment: Turns out [this was also reported last year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271607/double-hats-on-profile-page) but we didn't get around to fixing it. Valid bug report of course, but since it's not really creating a problem, I can't promise you a fix this year either. Think of it as having earned an extra hat ;)

Comment: @balpha: Ha, I seem to be hitting my head on the same issue. Another hat does soften the blow...

Comment: Oh hah I didn't even notice that you also reported the one last year.

Comment: @balpha: I just viewed my profile on StackApps and [didn't see the double hat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5mfn.png). Has this been fixed?

Comment: Not that I know of. But it's possible that this depends on timing, and thus there's a chance of it not happening.